# VBA вставить данные рядом с диапазоном вставленным от макроса

Tags: excel, vba

Макрос копирует диапазон с донора в столбец B, кол-во строк в доноре меняется. можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы в столбец А вставлялась текущая дата, рядом со всеми данными от макроса? (чтобы строк было заполнено столько же, сколько макрос скопировал). И\или в столбец Т сумма каждой по строке с C по S.

```html
Sub updateV_ostatki()
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With
    
    Dim wbksrc As Workbook
    Dim wbkdst As Workbook
    Dim shtsrc As Worksheet
    Dim shtdst As Worksheet

    Set wbksrc = Workbooks.Open("C:\pp.xls")
    Set wbkdst = Workbooks.Open("C:\Остатки.xlsm")
    Set shtsrc = wbksrc.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set shtdst = wbkdst.Sheets("Данные")

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Откорректировать диапазон-источник '
    wbksrc.Activate: shtsrc.Activate
    shtsrc.Range(shtsrc.Range("A5"), shtsrc.Range("R5").End(xlDown)).Copy
    ' Откорректировать диапазон-приёмник '
    shtdst.Paste Destination:=shtdst.Range("B:B").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    
    wbksrc.Close savechanges:=False
    wbkdst.Save
    wbkdst.Close
    
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ну у тебя же ж всё нужное есть - только ноль с единицей местами поменять...

Comment: *И\или в столбец Т сумма каждой по строке с C по S* - это непонятно. Вставка даты - в ответе

Comment: @vikttur криво написал я. В столбец Т проставлять сумму по каждой строке, числовые значения начинаются с столбца С, заканчиваются в S (допустим сумма ячеек с C5 по S5) и так пока не кончатся значения для суммы (как с датой)

Comment: В ответ добавил цикл для суммировия (после записи в массив и перед открытием другой книги)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ДиапазонСтолбца_А.Value = Date
```

Вариант кода:

```
Sub updateV_ostatki2()
    Dim aTemp()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With
    Set wbksrc = Workbooks.Open("C:\pp.xls")

    With wbk
        With .Sheets("Sheet1")
            i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
            aTemp = .Range("A5:S" & i).Value ' добавлен столбец для суммы'
        End With

        .Close
    End With

    For i = 1 To UBound(aTemp)
        aTemp(i, 19) = Empty

         For j = 3 To 18
            aTemp(i, 19) = aTemp(i, 19) + aTemp(i, j)
         Next j
    Next i

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Остатки.xlsm")

    With wbk
        With .Sheets("Данные")
            i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Cells(i, 1).Resize(UBound(aData), 1).Value = Date
            .Cells(i, 2).Resize(UBound(aData), UBound(aData, 2)).Value = aTemp
        End With

        .Save: .Close
    End With

    Set wbk = Nothing
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
End Sub
```

Comment: не могу понять ошибку в  With .Sheets("Sheet1"). ошибка 91 Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Потеряли закрытие оператора `End With`